# How can I access a method of owner JFrame in a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have to create a login `JFrame` and I need username in all the `JDialog`s that are owned by `JFrame`. How should I implement this?

I tried the following code.

```
class MyFrame extends Jframe {

    public getusername() {
        return username;
    }

    createGui() {
        JButton btnsubmit;
        btnsubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new MyJDialog(MyFrame.this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in the `JDialog` I am trying to use `getusername()` in this way

```
MyJDialog(JFrame frame) {
    super(frame);
    String us=frame.getusername();
}
```

but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example won't compile...

Comment: If this username is going to be used many times in your App, it is recommended to use `static String` to save username.

Comment: While making edits, I had to cringe at `createGui()`. How can that possible work? You need a return type, and it is best to make it private: `private void createGui()`. Also, learn to [indent your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar I wouldn't say that. What if you want to login in another user at the same time within the application? And yes, I work in an application that does this

Answer (score 2):

`getusername` is not a valid method for `JFrame`.

You should be specifying the concrete implementation within the dialogs constructor...

```
MyJDialog(MyFrame frame) {...}
```